# How to change the blog posts view when navigating through categories?

Tags: sharepoint-online

currently I've been struggling for a while with the following problem:

In my SharePoint blog site I have the following default view of posts:
http://s16.postimg.org/yvmu0j51x/Default_site.jpg

When I click on a category, I get the following view of posts:
http://s29.postimg.org/58lm8p993/Category_site.jpg

Is there any possibility to get the same way of showing post as how it looks on the default site? So with Image, with body etc. But then only filtered based on category.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please see below the answer to the post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9cdb3574-cd20-446c-b9cc-8309b54b4e28/how-to-change-the-blog-posts-view-when-navigating-through-categories?forum=sharepointgeneral